# Configure what is sent to Sentry with PHP

Tags: php, error-reporting, sentry

I try to set up Sentry in my non-framework-php project. It works like a charm but one thing is bothering me:

The code is very unstrict and notice-prone. Imagining sending for every user click sometimes 50 notices to sentry seems to be a big overhead. (And no, fixing all those things is unfortunately not in the budget!)

So my question: Is there a way to tell sentry just to send errors with level `WARNING` and above?

This is my code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);
require_once 'Raven/Autoloader.php';
Raven_Autoloader::register();

$client = new Raven_Client('myurl');
$error_handler = new Raven_ErrorHandler($client);
$error_handler->registerExceptionHandler();
$error_handler->registerErrorHandler();
$error_handler->registerShutdownFunction();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at the handlers you are setting. For instance, you can do this:

```
$error_handler = new \Raven_ErrorHandler($client);
$error_handler->registerErrorHandler(true, E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
```

This would only send certain errors. The ExceptionHandler is 'safe' to add I think, but take care with the shutdownhandler.

Some more info: the shutdownhandler is a bit 'greedy'.
It calls the `handleFatalError` function, but this does handle MORE then just fatal errors. For my system (but I have a more complex logging system) this is enough, but if you start missing errors because of the shutdownfunction not being there, you should make a child-class for the `ErrorHandler` file, and override that `handleFatalError()` function.

If you look at the code, you see that it calls the private `getErrorTypesToProcess`, which returns the extra types you can give it, combined with this list:

```
private $validErrorTypes = array(
    E_ERROR,
    E_WARNING,
    E_PARSE,
    E_NOTICE,
    E_CORE_ERROR,
    E_CORE_WARNING,
    E_COMPILE_ERROR,
    E_COMPILE_WARNING,
    E_USER_ERROR,
    E_USER_WARNING,
    E_USER_NOTICE,
    E_STRICT,
    E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR,
    E_DEPRECATED,
    E_USER_DEPRECATED,
);
```

And that is a bit big for me :)
But as said, you might be like me, and just skipping the shutdownfunction works fine?

For reference, see these threads:

https://github.com/getsentry/raven-php/issues/168
https://github.com/getsentry/raven-php/pull/181
https://github.com/getsentry/raven-php/issues/266

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! I tried to pass the errors to the errorHandler like mentioned above in your post but it still sends the notices. Am I missing something?

Comment: did you remove the shutdown-handler call?

Comment: ok, thought this was a second approach! now it works - thanks :) I'll give it a try with subclassing the error handler!

Comment: In the end I needed to manipulate the code so I can use the shutdown handler. Else I don't get noticed on big crashes... But for now it seems to work.